# What does String [][] means in C#?

Tags: c#

EG.

```
String [ ][ ] LinesSplitByComma1 =
    File.ReadAllLines("Filepath").Select(s => s.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 10):

An array of arrays of strings.

It's reading a file and creating an array where each element is a line from the file, represented by an array of strings created by splitting that line at commas.

So a file like

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
asdas,ertert,xcvxcvx
```

Would be represented as

```
LinesSplitByComma1[0][0] = "a"
LinesSplitByComma1[0][1] = "b"
LinesSplitByComma1[0][2] = "c"
LinesSplitByComma1[1][0] = "1"
LinesSplitByComma1[1][1] = "2"
LinesSplitByComma1[1][2] = "3"
LinesSplitByComma1[2][0] = "asdas"
LinesSplitByComma1[2][1] = "ertert"
LinesSplitByComma1[2][2] = "xcvxcvx"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an array of string arrays.  In your specific case, you have an array of lines, each of which is split into an array of comma-separated tokens.

```
string[][] lines  = File.ReadAllLines("Filepath").Select(s => s.Split(',')).ToArray();
string[]   tokens = lines[i];
string     token  = tokens[j];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a "jagged" array; an array of arrays of strings. It is one form of "two-dimensional array"; the other is a "rectangular array" which can be declared like `string[,]`.

The difference is inherent in the name; a jagged array's sub-arrays can each have a different number of values, while a rectangular array's sub-arrays are each the same length.

In memory, they look very different. A jagged array is initially created as an array of "pointers" to other arrays, and as the jagged array is initialized, the arrays that form the second dimension of the construct are each individually created and referenced in the "buckets" of the first-dimension array:

```
string[][] jaggedArray = new string[3][]; //the first dimension contains three elements
jaggedArray[0] = new string[5]; //now the first element is an array of 5 elements.
jaggedArray[1] = new string[4]; //the second element's array can be a different length.
jaggedArray[0][2] = "Test";
var secondDim = jaggedArray[1]; //A higher-dimension array of a jagged array can be independently referenced.
```

A rectangular array, however, is created at one time as a single block of memory:

```
string[,] rectArray = new string[3,5]; //the entire 3x5 block of string refs is now reserved.
rectArray[0,4] = "Test"; //we didn't have to declare the second-dimension array.
//However, the following will not compile:
var secondDim = rectArray[1]; //a rectangular array's higher dimensions can't be "severed".
```